# How to get which user has liked page from FB page plugin

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebooksdk.net

I used Facebook Page Plugin to display page like widget (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) on my site. When I run my site FB page widget is open with like and share buttons. When user clicks on like it opens a popup and prompt user to enter FB login once user enters it and authenticated the widget is refreshed and now like button is greyed out. How do I know the user details who liked the page? I want to save these details so that I can check if user has already liked the page or not if yes they can use the site directly if not then they must first like the page and then use the site. My application is built on C# ASP.Net MVC. I also want the request to Facebook should go from  it from C# code. Let me know the correct process in case I'm not following correct procedure.

FB page like widget code is

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://facebook.com/codeblends" data-width="380" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-hide-cta="true"
             data-show-posts="false"></div>
```

In JS

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '@ReadConfig.FacebookAppID',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: '@ReadConfig.FacebookAPIVersion'        
    });

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', finished_rendering);
(function (d, s, id) {

    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check if a user liked a Page is to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permission. You would have to go through Facebooks review process with that permission, and Facebook will definitely not approve the usage for your case, because what you are trying to achieve is not allowed. **Like gating is not allowed since many years.**

You must read the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: @lunschn user_likes permission is to get all pages user has liked. I don't need this. I only want to know which user has liked my page using Facebook's page like widget (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin). Is there a call back which I can implement? Or what is way around?

Comment: i know, but that´s not possible and as you wrote in your question, you would use it for something that is not allowed anyway.

Comment: @lunschn What is the way out? If do not use page widget then how do I do it? login with FB then get the likes?

Comment: you don´t. it´s not possible and not allowed. there is no way out.